# PHP get image from server

Tags: php, image, apache, server, client

I am trying to display an image from a PHP server.
Here it is my function:

```
function get_file($path) {
    $fileToGet = $GLOBALS['homedir'].$path;
    //echo $fileToGet.PHP_EOL;
    if (file_exists($fileToGet)) {
      //echo 'file exists';
      header('Content-Type: image/png');
      header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileToGet));
      echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

I am using the browser or postman and the image is invalid.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I edited a little bit your function:

```
function get_file( $path ){
    $fileToGet = $GLOBALS['homedir'];
    if( substr( $fileToGet, -1) != '/' ){
        // add trailing slash if needed
        $fileToGet .= '/';
    }
    $fileToGet .= $path;

    if (file_exists($fileToGet)) {
      header('Content-Type: image/png');
      header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileToGet));
      echo file_get_contents($fileToGet);
    }
}
```

Just a security hint: if `$path` comes from the user there may be a problem because he will be able to access to some other file. 
Think about this code:

```
get_file( $_GET['path'] );
```

then the user can call this url

```
yoursite/yourpage.php?path=../../../mypreciousimage.png
```

Comment: I added your code and it seems that file_get_contents($fileToGet) stops the PHP. Here it is the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10MZi2JBLuUu7gS03mFDjuPZSdykhX3QX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If I comment out the header with content-type then I got some response like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y9898QkQK7DzXCRzSKCWFPByK73zGG7k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found the issue: before `readfile() -> ob_clean(); flush();`

Answer (score 0):

You're not outputting the contents of the file you're reading:

```
file_get_contents($file);
```

You'll need to echo it:

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Or:

```
readfile($file);
```

You'll probably also want to add `exit;` to the end of that function, to ensure that no other code runs and that no other output gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print file_get_contents($file);
```

Instead of

```
file_get_contents($file);
```